# Remote Hand Held controller not operating properly with three 3 Way Switches

Tags: electrical

I installed controller in the fan for the hand held remote but only the light control on the remote works to turn everything on and off. Fan speeds don't change when I press them but the high speed turns the light on also. Right now one 3 way at the front door is off and the split foyer 3 ways(top and bottom of the stairs) are in the up position.How does this novice correct this situation.

No Clue...

Comment: You have three locations to control the the lights from manual switches? If so be aware that one of those needs to be a 4-way switch instead of a 3-way.

Comment: Hello Mike,  Thanks for the response ...How do I know if one of them isn't a already a four way any way to check with out taking the switch plate covers off...

Comment: What make and model is your fan remote, and are you willing to look into alternative options for a fan remote system? Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved (with the breaker off, of course)?

Comment: No. To check you need to look at the switches. The 3-way will have three screws and the 4-way has four screw terminals.